# How to select only some fields using JPA criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Student entity and want to select only two fields - `id` and `age`. After reading different posts I wrote the following code:

```
CriteriaQuery<Student> criteriaQuery = ..
var root = criteriaQuery.from(Student.class);
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("age"));
typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Student> students = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

However, it doesn't work. How to do it using hibernate jpa provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want two fields and use `multiselect` you can use a TupleQuery like in the example below:

```java
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
var root = criteriaQuery.from(Student.class);

criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("age"));

typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<Tuple> students = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

To access the values of the tuples use the `get` method of it.

E.g.:

```java
Long id = (Long) students.get(0).get(0);
```